# Python inline elif possible?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

```
'Hello ' + ('there' if name is None else name)
```

Is the equivalent of

```
msg = 'Hello '
if name is None:
    msg += 'there'
else:
    msg += name
```

What is the equivalent of this:

```
msg = 'Hello '
if name is None:
    msg += 'there'
elif name == 'Mr Anderson'
    msg += 'Neo'
else:
    msg += name
```

**EDIT: for reference here is the code I wanted to shrink**

```
srepr = '\'Modify '
if self.register == 'p':
    srepr += 'Pointer'
elif self.register == 'v':
    srepr += 'Value'
else
    srepr += 'Unknown'
srepr += ' By ' + str(self.delta) + '\''
```

Comment: `srepr+={'p': 'Pointer', 'v': 'Value'}.get(self.register,'Unknown')`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
msg = "Hi " + ("there" if not name else ("Neo" if name == "Anderson" else name))
```

I think that's pretty unreadable, though.

Comment: You have unnecessary parentheses which make this less readable.  See my answer for a clearer solution.

Comment: @glenn. I added those parentheses in order to make it more readable, but I guess that's subjective. In any case I think we all agree nobody should ever write nothing similar.

Comment: Nice answer - but if I ever see this in a production codebase, I'm going to have a long day.  :P

Answer (score 8):

Use a dictionary to perform a mapping:

```
srepr = "'Modify " + {"p": "Pointer", "v": "value"}.get(self.register, "Unknown")
```

(by the way, instead of `'\'...'` you can use `"'...` for a bit more clarity.

Answer (score 7):

```
msg = 'Hello ' + (
    'there' if name is None else
    'Neo' if name == 'Mr Anderson' else
    name
)
```

This is a reiteration of several other answers, but with nicer formatting. I consider this most readable, and this is the approach I would use.

Answer (score 3):

```
'Hello ' + \
('there' if name is None else \
    'Neo' if name == 'Mr Anderson' else \
    name)
```

I recommend against this; if your conditions become this complex, stick it in a function.

Comment: This is the approach I would use, but as it's written here, the formatting is unnecessarily noisy. See my answer for a version without backslashes and with consistent indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Do not do it.

Do this instead:

```
% python -m this | sed 's/^R.*/======>&<======/'
```

### EDIT: For reference, here is how I would refactor this code...

Whenever I see `elif`, I think `dict`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Shrink(object):
    types = {
            'p': 'Pointer',
            'v': 'Value',
            }

    def shrink_this(self):
        return "'Modify %s By %s'" % (
                self.types.get(self.register, 'Unknown'), self.delta)

import unittest
class TestShrink(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_p(self):
        s = Shrink();
        s.register = 'p'
        s.delta = 'delta'
        self.assertEquals("'Modify Pointer By delta'", s.shrink_this())

    def test_u(self):
        s = Shrink();
        s.register = 'u'
        s.delta = 'echo'
        self.assertEquals("'Modify Unknown By echo'", s.shrink_this())

    def test_v(self):
        s = Shrink();
        s.register = 'v'
        s.delta = 'foxtrot'
        self.assertEquals("'Modify Value By foxtrot'", s.shrink_this())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Were you to need to add `r` for `reference` or `pp` for `pointer-to-pointer`, only `types` requires a change and your code remains readable.

> Readability counts.

Comment: Ouch. Why the down-vote? "The Zen of Python" is important reading for any Python programmer (along with PEP008). The `sed` command emphasises the point.

Comment: The question says Python 3.x. Use `return "'Modify {} By {}'".format(                self.types.get(self.register, 'Unknown'), self.delta)`

Comment: And a second down-vote: "If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!" --Be Honest, SO FAQ <http://stackoverflow.com/faq>

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
msg= 'Hello ' + {name is None: 'there', name == 'Mr Anderson': 'Neo'}.get(True, name)
```

So either of `name is None` or `name == 'Mr Anderson'` is `True`, or none of them is True, then `name` will be used.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, run 'pip install pyswitch'

Then:

```
import pyswitch

mySwitch = pyswitch.Switch()

@mySwitch.case(None):
def gotNone(value):
    return 'Hello there'

@mySwitch.case('Mr. Anderson')
def gotMrAnderson(value):
    return 'Hello Neo'

@mySwitch.default
def gotDefault(value):
    return 'Hello %s' % value

msg = mySwitch.switch(None)  # Returns 'Hello there'
msg = mySwitch.switch('Mr. Anderson')  # Returns 'Hello Neo'
msg = mySwitch.switch('OoglyMoogly')  # Returns 'Hello OoglyMoogly'
```

Comment: As the length of your 'elif' chain grows, this solution's appeal grows.  It's basically a something like a C language switch statement for Python.  See http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pyswitch&submit=search

Comment: if it comes to that, one could just use a dictionary with cases as keys, and a possibly lambda function as values. way much simpler that a `pyswitch` even in large statments.