# Conditional string formatting with if, elif

Tags: python, string, format

one step further than [How to implement conditional string formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244909/how-to-implement-conditional-string-formatting)

Basically: is it possible to add `if`, `elif`.... `else` in a format string?

```
l = ['it', 'en', 'es']

for i in l:
    print('{tit}'.format(tit='Ciao' if i == 'it' elif i == 'en' tit='Hi' else 'Hola'))
```

Comment: This would make a lot more sense as `{'it': 'Ciao', 'en': ...}`. While it's possible to have inline `if` expressions, which you could even chain to emulate something like `elif`, it's an insane an unmaintainable structure.

Comment: the general workflow I have is more complex to have a single dictionary like you suggested. Why is it insane?

Comment: If your workflow is so complex, why do you want to do all of it in a single line?

Comment: Just look at it, it's unreadable (and the actual working equivalent wouldn't be much better). Also, every time you may add one more item to `l`, you need to keep adding to that already unreadable expression everywhere you use such a thing in your code. That's why it's much better to define something like a dict upfront where the data which belongs together is defined together, and the rest is a generic algorithm which doesn't need to be hardcoded to `if i == 'it' …`. Even if your actual case is more complex, there *are* certainly solutions that follow this better pattern.

Comment: ok then I'll refactor the code. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Author of the questions asks if it is possible to add if, elif, else in string formating. So, I do assume author wants to change the value of the string depending on some condition but wants to use if, elif, else for some reasons.

Here is my answer:

```
t = ['Ciao' if x == 'it' else ('Hi' if x == 'en' else 'Hola') for x in ['it', 'en', 'es']]
```

I personally do not like if, elif, else logic in such case.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would not recommend it - to answer the question:

It is **not** possible to use `elif` in a format string.

It is however possible to use nested conditional expressions:

```
l = ['it', 'en', 'es']

for i in l:
    print('{tit}'.format(tit=('Ciao' if i == 'it' else 'Hi' if i == 'en' else 'Hola')))
```

outputs:

```
Ciao
Hi
Hola
```

see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions